# Is there a way to treat a cl_image as a cl_mem?

Tags: opencl

I've been working on speeding up some image processing code written in OpenCL, and I've found that for my kernel, buffers (`cl_mem`) are significantly faster than images (`cl_image`).

So I want to process my images as `cl_mem`, but unfortunately I'm stuck with an API that only spits out `cl_images`. I'm using a OS X API `clCreateImageFromIOSurface2DAPPLE` that creates an image for me.

Is there any way to take a `cl_image` and treat it as a `cl_mem`? When I've tried to do that I get an error when running my kernel.

I've tried copying the image to a buffer using `clEnqueueCopyImageToBuffer` but that's also too slow. Any ideas? Thanks in advance

PS: I believe my kernel operating on a buffer is much faster because I can do a `vload4` and load 4 pixels at a time, vs `read_imagei` which does just one.

Comment: Do you have some measurements to back up that operating on images is slower? GPUs are intended to be used with images so the fast guess is that they will work better with image processing. Regarding your question I don't think it is possible. Images are stored using specific formats, pading, etc. If you could directly cast it, it would have different formats depending on the driver manufacturer.

Comment: Do you have one or four channels in the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **cannot** treat an OpenCL image as memory. The memory layout of an image is private to the implementation and should be considered unknown.

If your code creates the image, however, you could create a buffer and then use cl_khr_image2d_from_buffer. Otherwise write a kernel that copies the data from image to buffer and see if it is faster than clEnqueueCopyImageToBuffer (unlikely).